# Google AppEngine gives Jersey ServletContainer ClassNotFoundException

Tags: google-app-engine, jersey, jax-rs, classnotfoundexception

I am using Eclipse Indigo with Google AppEngine SDK (and no GWT)

Project setup starting with a clean default project:

- Java in use is the Oracle JDK 7 but changed project settings to generate 1.6 code and source code compatibility also set to 1.6
- Added 2 external jars to BuildPath from Glassfish Java EE 6 + JDK 7 installation
- jersey-core.jar
- jersey-gf-server.jar
- jersey-gf-server.jar contains com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
- Fixed Eclipse markers complaining that the jar files would not be found in the deployed app -- accepted suggested fix for each to copy them to war/WEB-INF/lib folder
- Deployed successfully
- Upon accessing the regular non-Jersey hello-world servlet, I get the error in AppEngine logs: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.provider.container.servlet.ServletContainer`

Answer (score 2):

the class ServletContainer is in the jersey-bundle.jar

Answer (score 2):

You should add `jersey-servlet.jar` as well. At some point this class was migrated there.